# Move legend down a bit more

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have 2 questions:
1- How to lower the legend so it doesn't override the x-axis
2- How can I avoid the 5*10^-2 in the x-axis and get 0.05

```
       \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{url,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
       \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=0.8, 
    xlabel={$[s]$}, 
    ylabel={$\phi$},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.8,
    width=1\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.17)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left}
    ]
    
    \addplot[black,dashed, domain=0:0.2]{0.9}; \label{gamma_max}
    \addlegendentry{down}
    \addplot[black,dash dot, domain=0:0.2]{0.61}; \label{gamma_min}
    \addlegendentry{down 2}
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{model}}
    \label{fig:apertura_max_min}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
       \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=0.2, 
    xlabel={$[s]$}, 
    ylabel={$Amplitude$},
    ymin=0,ymax=1.0,
    width=1\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.17)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left,
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed zerofill,precision=2}}
    ]
    
    \addplot[black,dashed, domain=0:0.2]{0.9}; \label{gamma_max}
    \addlegendentry{lower 1}
    \addplot[black,dash dot, domain=0:0.2]{0.61}; \label{gamma_min}
    \addlegendentry{lower 2}
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{model 2}}
    \label{fig:andamento_valvola}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \caption{\textit{valve model}}
    \label{fig:costruzione_valvola}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why you not put legend above diagrams, for example in one line?

Comment: I moved up the legend but thee 2 squares are now different in size

Answer (score 1):

> How to lower the legend so it doesn't override the x-axis

You can change **legend location** by changing the numbers inside `at={(0.5,-0.45)}` in `legend style=...`. You already had this in your file, I just changed the numbers so they work for your plots.

Same can be done with **xlabel**, which was also overlapping some stuff. This time I played with values `yshift=-12pt,xshift=65pt` in `xlabel style={at={(0,0)},yshift=-12pt,xshift=65pt}`.

> How can I avoid the 5*10^-2 in the x-axis and get 0.05

When formating **x-axis values** `xticklabel style=...` you have to add another `fixed`. For you to get 0.05 instead of 5*10^-2, the number format must be as follows `/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2`.

When I changed the locations of the legends, the first plot moved down a bit, so I encapsulated `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}` with `\hspace*{0em}\raisebox{0em}{ ... }`, value in **hspace** moves plot horizontaly, value in **raisebox** moves plot vertically. I moved the first plot **10pt** up and it looks they are leveled.

**Result**
[image: Result after changes in code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{url,amsfonts,epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \hspace*{0pt}\raisebox{10pt}{\begin{tikzpicture}                        % Edited here
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=0.8, 
    xlabel={$[s]$}, 
    ylabel={$\phi$},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.8,
    width=1\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.35)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left},    % Edited here
    xlabel style={at={(0,0)},yshift=0pt,xshift=65pt}]                       % Edited here
    \addplot[black,dashed, domain=0:0.2]{0.9}; \label{gamma_max}
    \addlegendentry{down}
    \addplot[black,dash dot, domain=0:0.2]{0.61}; \label{gamma_min}
    \addlegendentry{down 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}                                                      % Edited here
    \caption{\textit{model}}
    \label{fig:apertura_max_min}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \hspace*{0em}\raisebox{0em}{\begin{tikzpicture}                         % Edited here
    \begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=0.2, 
    xlabel={$[s]$}, 
    ylabel={$Amplitude$},
    ymin=0,ymax=1.0,
    width=1\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.45)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left,     % Edited here
    xticklabel style={rotate=-90,/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed  zerofill,precision=2}},    % Edited here
    xlabel style={at={(0,0)},yshift=-12pt,xshift=65pt}]                     % Edited here
    \addplot[black,dashed, domain=0:0.2]{0.9}; \label{gamma_max}
    \addlegendentry{lower 1}
    \addplot[black,dash dot, domain=0:0.2]{0.61}; \label{gamma_min}
    \addlegendentry{lower 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}                                                      % Edited here
    \caption{\textit{model 2}}
    \label{fig:andamento_valvola}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \caption{\textit{valve model}}
    \label{fig:costruzione_valvola}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! +1 for welcome :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks ;)